# javascript code does not work as i want it

Tags: javascript, html, css

I was trying to practice a course but i got stuck on [this step](https://watchandcode.com/courses/60264/lectures/956111). I don't know where the problem is?

```js
var todoList = {
  todos: [],

  displayTodo: function() {
    if (this.todos.length === 0) {
      console.log('todos are empty')
    } else {
      console.log("my todos: ");
      for (i = 0; i < this.todos.length; i++) { // i think the problem is into this for loop
        if (this.todos[i].complited === true) {
          console.log("(X) " + this.todos[i].todoText);
        } else {
          console.log("( ) " + this.todos[i].todoText);
        }
      }
    }
  },

  addTodo: function(todoText) {
    this.todos.push({
      todoText: todoText,
      completed: false

    });
    this.displayTodo();
  },
  changeTodo: function(index, newValue) {
    this.todos[index].Text = newValue;
    this.displayTodo();
  },

  deletTodo: function(position) {
    this.todos.splice(position, 1);
    this.displayTodo();

  },
  toggelComplited: function(position) // this i working correctly
  {
    var todo = this.todos[position];
    todo.completed = !todo.completed;
    this.displayTodo();
  }

};
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <h1>Hello bilal!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

this is what i see in my console (look at the comment below  ==> //....):

> todoList.displayTodo()
>
> < todos are empty
>
> todoList.addTodo("first")
>
> < my todos: 
>   < ( ) first
>
> todoList.addTodo("second")
>
> < my todos:
>
> < ( ) first
>
> < ( ) second
>
> todoList.todos[ 0 ]
>
> < {todoText: "first", completed: false}
>
> todoList.todos[ 1 ]
>
> < {todoText: "second", completed: false}
>
> todoList.toggelComplited(0)
>
> < my todos:
>
> < ( ) first // this line should show me this: (X) first
>
> < ( ) second

Comment: Please explain what your issue is and what output you would expect. I've reformatted and edited your question to fit to the guidelines you can find [here](https://stackoverflow.com/help). Does not work is not a problem description we can work with.

Comment: is this a typo in the question body or in your code? `this.todos[i].complited === true`  you have `completed` (correct spelling) everywhere else.

Comment: the lie befor last must show this : 
(X) first

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like a typo for "completed" in for loop

```
if (this.todos[i].**complited** === true) {
```

Comment: it's the sae thing i did